# SีQL update status bill payment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables in my Postgresql database, SALES and ORDERS together they join with FK relation many to one.
1 ORDERID can have many SALEID because customer don't like to pay all of them in one time. So I want to update column "STATUS" in ORDERS table. if the payment is not complete but the customer ever paid before.

```
    update "Schema"."ORDERS" as o set "STATUS" = 'in progress'
    from "Schema"."SALES" as s
    where o."ORDERID" in (select s."ORDERID" from "Schema"."SALES" as s group by s."ORDERID") and 
    s."SUMMARY" <> o."SUMMARY"
```

This code not error but the result not exactly true because i want only bill that not complete.The result also update complete bill.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
UPDATE "Schema"."ORDERS" o
SET STATUS = 'in progress'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "Schema"."SALES" s
              WHERE s.ORDERID = o.ORDERID AND s.SUMMARY <> o.SUMMARY);
```